# How can I display/hide menu items with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, menu, menuitem

[See update at the end]

I'm working with Zend framework, in PHP and I have some difficulties with Zend Navigation. It's my first question here, so if something's wrong with it, just tell me and I'll correct it.

I have a menu looking like this in my application

```
Home 
Login
Logout
Member's Page
```

I have a navigation xml file containing my menu.

```
<nav>
 <home>
    <label>Home</label>
    <uri>/</uri>
 </home>
 <login>
    <label>Login</label>
    <uri>/index/login</uri>
 </login>
 <logout>
    <label>Logout</label>
    <uri>/index/logout</uri>
 </logout>
 <member>
    <label>Member's Page</label>
    <uri>/index/member</uri>
 </member>
</nav>
```

Also a menu.phtml containing this

```
<div class="top-level">
<?php
foreach ($this->container as $page) {
    if ($page->isVisible()) {
        if ($page->isActive(true)) {
            if ($page->isActive(false)
                )$page->setClass("active");
            else
                $page->setClass("open");
            echo $this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page);
//... the same continue for the 3 menu level
```

Finally, in my layout.phtml, I have this to render the menu

```
<?php
      $partial = array('menu.phtml', 'default');
      $this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial($partial);
      echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render();
?>
```

For now, my menu works good, but I can't have Login and Logout always displayed in my menu. So, what I need to do, is to hide Login when I'm logged in, and to hide Logout when I'm logged out. It looked pretty simple when I started, and it still does, but I can't make it work. I don't know how and if I can hide and show item depending on logged users. I really need to make it work, because I will need to hide/display other items in the future.

So is there a way of doing that ?

Thanks !

EDIT :

I'm currently not using Zend::Auth or Zend_ACL for roles and authorization. If I want to know if the user is logged in or not, I have a token in the session that is valid only when the user is logged in. I'd like my menu to work without changing that if it's possible.

UPDATE :

I had it working in another way than those suggested. I'm really not sure it's a clean way, but it's doing the job for now. So now, my xml navigation file look like

```
<menuAnonymous>
     <home>
     <label>Login</label>
        <uri>/login</uri>
     </home>
    </menuAnonymous>
    <menuLogged>
     <home>
        <label>Logout</label>
        <uri>/Logout</uri>
     </home>
    </menuLogged>
```

I initialize both in my bootstrap like this.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'menuNotLogged');    
$container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
Zend_Registry::set('main',$container);
```

And then, in my layout, I look at my token and display the menu depending on that.

```
if ($tokenValid) {
     echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render(Zend_Registry::get('main')); 
} else {
     echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render(Zend_Registry::get('logged'));
}
```

So it's working like I want now, but I still want to do it cleaner, so if you have any suggestions to help me ... thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my question with the solution I used, maybe I'll find a better way to do it later but for now this is it. I didn't find the solution here, that's why I'm answering my own question. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the "Leveraging Zend_Navigator" webinar on http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework. It explains how you can tie your navigation to specifiec roles/ACL.

Comment: But I'm not using ACL, I will edit my question with these details, thank you !

Comment: Just have a look at the webinar. You just store some extra info in your XML and pass info to the navigation to get the set of relevant items. So you could easily just create 2 fake roles (one anonymous, one "logged in user") and use these to display the correct menu items for your use case.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, wasn't notified and was working on something else. I'll take a look at it, and I'll come back to accept an answer depending on what's working. Thank you